# LINUX : How to Log in as Root (Ubuntu 10.04)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, login, administrator, root

**I want to use the whole operating system as an administrator.**

I know I can log in as a root in the `Terminal` by typing this:

```
su
Password
```

But in this way I'm logged in only in the terminal.

I want to be able to delete/edit/open any files from anywhere on my computer.

**EDIT:**

I have a `server` in `/Files Systems/opt/` and my `PHP` files says that I need to give permission to make it work that's why I need permission for everything.

Comment: The php message did NOT say you needed to give it root permissions.  It says it needs to exist and be readable.  That's a whole different thing with multiple possible solutions that don't involve root at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to be able to delete/edit/open any files from anywhere on my computer.

Elevate using gksu from the terminal

`gksu nautilus` will start nautilus, the file manager as root.

And as [hotei mentioned](https://superuser.com/questions/189942/linux-how-to-log-in-as-root-ubuntu-10-4/189946#189946) - be careful

Answer (score 2):

Once you've logged in as root you can (usually) run other programs - such as gedit to edit files or nautilus (file manager).  It isn't (usually) wise to do this unless you need root permissions to do something but it's your system.

Comment: Thanks @hotei for your answer, you are true with `nautilus` but the problem is that I'm not the one who needs to `open/edit/delete` the files, I have a server on it and my `PHP` files says that I need to give permission to make it work.

Comment: You may need root perms to install php, but it's not required afterwards.  Your php files will be executed by the web server which is usually running as a daemon (started when the system is booted).  My web files (*.php) are not owned by root but rather by me, so I don't need root permission to change them.  Maybe I'm not understanding your problem...

Comment: check out my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739754/include-error-in-php-on-linux-ubuntu-10-4

Comment: @CIRK: FYI - I commented on your question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to *be* root on an Ubuntu box, you've got to enable the root account by assigning it a password.  A simple

```
sudo passwd root
```

will do the trick.  You'll have to enter your password first (to get past the sudo hurdle), then set a password for the root account.  All that said, don't do this!  The only remotely legit reason I can think of for this is so you can set up password-less ssh logins between boxes as root, and that's not a good enough reason, in my opinion.